# not getting alert even after making the required attribute in <select> tag

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am pretty new to the front-end. I have this situation where I am trying to make the  tag as required since it is mandatory.

```
<select id="some_id" multiple="multiple" class="some-class" name="some-name" required>
```

I went through few resources online, According to them if none of the options in  is selected it will not submit the form and it will give an alert.

How it Is working for me is  the form is not submitted if none of the options in `<select>` is selected which is as expected but it is not giving me any alerts asking me to select at least an option.
please help

Comment: Are you sure your first option tag has empty value , like, `<option value="">Please select</option>`

Comment: is it mandotory?

Comment: Yes, try that.
And it will not show an actual alert, it would show a validation error like https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_select_required